# Can you add dice from Traits when you make a defense roll (and didn't do Active Defense)?

Tags: conflicts, mistborn

For example, if you labeled a trait 'shield fighter' and are currently using a shield, could you add a die for that trait when defending against a physical attack, even if you declared an attack action?

Other examples would be 'renown' when defending in a social conflict or 'stalwart' when defending against some mental attacks.